# Dynamic element not attaching to on() function?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, dynamic-binding

Im currently using the on() function to attach to dynamic elements in my application which are loaded initially but then reloaded via ajax. Due to the reloading this code

```
$('a.open-drawer').on('click', function(event){..});
```

Works well initially but on ajax reload it doesnt. I've resolved to use the data selector in the on() function instead

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.open-drawer', function(event){..});
```

But this one now doesnt work completely!!!! Ive used this second option repeatedly in my application and it works in the other cases. What Im I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: @Andreas Short of adding the whole application Im not sure how to describe my iisue.

Comment: As you've already noted yourself this should work. Without a **minimal**, complete and verifiable example we cannot help you. Remove anything unrelated, add log messages, check the console for errors, fire up the debugger and step through your code, ...

Comment: @Andreas Let me synthesize a clear example to illustrate the issue, will post again if I come by the solution.